# Error on Authentication net 6 Unable to match key

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, keycloak, .net-6.0

I got the next error:

```
IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: 
kid: 'System.String'.
Exceptions caught:
 'System.Text.StringBuilder'. 
token: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.InternalValidators.ValidateLifetimeAndIssuerAfterSignatureNotValidatedJwt(SecurityToken securityToken, Nullable`1 notBefore, Nullable`1 expires, String kid, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, StringBuilder exceptionStrings)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

I'm using Net 6 on a api with keycloak, my local conf was
[image]
I have a public kid on RS256 but I don't know how to add it to JwtBearer configuration, I'm new on this

I try add on appSettings like

[image]

all of this is on dev options, I got the key from keycloak realm

Comment: Similar issue as mine. You don't seem to use the AddOpenIdConnect method, although not all your code is presented

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip the authentication signature for jwt token keycloak and check later with a method you can use this in .net 6

In Program.cs

```
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
 {
  option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
   {
     ValidateIssuer = false,
     ValidateAudience = false,
     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
     RequireSignedTokens = false,
     SignatureValidator = delegate (string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters) {
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);

        return jwt;
      },
      ValidateLifetime = false,
      RequireExpirationTime = false,
      ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
    };
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
     {
      OnTokenValidated = context =>
       {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };
});
```